# Make "socket.accept" in one thread execute before some code in another thread? (python3)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I want python to execute (similar to `subprocess.Popen()`?) an external socket connector AFTER I have another thread to block at `socket.accept()`.

```
import socket
import threading
import subprocess

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 3333


def getsock():
    server_sock = []

    def getsock_server():
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(1)
        accept_return = sock.accept()  # *** CRITICAL ACCEPT ***
        server_sock.append(accept_return[0])
        address = accept_return[1]
        return address

    thr = threading.Thread(target=getsock_server)
    thr.start()
    """Something that *must* be done after the CRITICAL ACCEPT 
       line is executing and the thread "thr" is blocked. Otherwise
       the program malfunctions and blows into some undebuggable
       complexity. ;(
       Although it is a connect operation, it may not be as innocent
       as belowing lines:        
           client_sock = socket.socket()
           client_sock.connect((host, port))
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ["./connector"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    thr.join()
    return server_sock[0]


conn, addr = getsock()
```

Basically, I need to have everything work like below in order:

```
1) thr.start()
2) sock.accept()
3) subprocess.Popen()
```

If 3) goes before 2), undesirable consequence will happen.

A solution without threads (I thought it first definitely, since threading is troublesome..) is impossible since when I `socket.accept()` I cannot just `subprocess.Popen()` without interrupting the accept.

Also I don't want to use `time.sleep(SOME_LARGE_VALUE)` as it is also uncontrollable (bug-prone, am I using the correct word?) and moreover, slow.

I have learned that: Python3 (CPython) has global interpreter lock (GIL) mechanics. At one time only one thread has the chance of executing. And if one thread blocks (in this case `socket.accept()`), the CPython will turn to another thread. (However, this does not help with the problem..)

Anyone knows a pythonic way (or a not-so-pythonic way) of enforcing the order?

Comment: "undesirable consequence"? How about giving us a hint? I could see wanting to do the call after the listen, but where exactly in the accept should the subprocess run? Just  before the accept, right after the accept? Why would it matter that the accept is blocking before the subprocess runs?

Comment: Once `listen(1)` returns, the TCP stack will queue up to 1 connect request in the background even if you haven't called `accept` yet. As long as you call `accept` before the other side gets bored and resets its connection, it will complete the connection.

Comment: I will have a try... Seem like I am far from familiar with socket system calls ... :P

Comment: However, what is a pythonic/nonpythonic solution if another such situation (that requires a blocking operation to block first and then another operation should proceed) occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listen` tells the network stack to start queuing incoming connection requests in the background. Each call to `accept` accepts the next request in the queue. It looks like your subprocess wants to connect back to this program. Just call it after the listen.

```
import socket
import threading
import subprocess

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 3333


def getsock():
    server_sock = []
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ["./connector"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return sock.accept()  # *** CRITICAL ACCEPT ***

conn, addr = getsock()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have been provided with the valid answer for your very specific case. However, if you prefer a more generic solution for a more generic problem, there are few different ways to achieve that.

Let's then define a problem: I want to schedule a job of preparing some resource to the worker thread, then wait in a main thread for resource to be ready. The preparation of the resource would be made only once. Of course, there is still valid question: why we just cannot run all things sequentially in a one thread? But let's consider this as an exercise introducing to the world of multithreading.

So, here is some skeleton python code:

```
import threading
import time
import random

data_ready=False

def do_sth():
    global data_ready

    def prepare_sth():
        global data_ready
        print("preparing, simulated by random wait")
        time.sleep(random.randrange(5,10))
        data_ready=True
        print("resource is ready")

    print("do_sth");
    thr = threading.Thread(target=prepare_sth)
    thr.start()

    # WAIT HERE

    if data_ready:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("ERROR")

do_sth()
```

Of course it does not work as expected and there will be an `ERROR` message somewhere in the output. But we can change our question to: *What put in place of `WAIT HERE`?*

The most obvious and the worst way to solve such problem would be active waiting:

```
while not data_ready:
    pass
```

Try to run this code and observe (using `top` on Linux) CPU usage. You will notice it grows up during the waiting. So, please do not do such things in real life.

It was specified that the resource preparation is done only once. So, the working thread can prepare the data and then we can just wait for this thread to finish in main thread. This would by mine preferred solution in such defined case.

```
thr.join()
```

And, finally, use a full blown lock and conditional variable scheme. It required some more changes, so a full code is pasted here:

```
import threading
import time
import random

data_ready=False

def do_sth():
    global data_ready
    lock=threading.Lock()
    cond=threading.Condition(lock)

    def prepare_sth():
        global data_ready
        with cond:
            print("preparing, simulated by random wait")
            time.sleep(random.randrange(5,10))
            data_ready=True
            print("resource is ready")
            cond.notify()

    print("do_sth");
    with cond:
        thr = threading.Thread(target=prepare_sth)
        thr.start()
        while not data_ready:
            print("waiting")
            cond.wait()

        if data_ready:
            print("OK")
        else:
            print("ERROR")

do_sth()
```

If you would need to prepare the resource (for example, some data) in a cyclic manner in one thread, and use it in another, it would a proper approach. Please look for *Producer-Consumer model*.

And last but not least. I have used a `global` specifier for `data_ready` variable, because I am lazy and this example is about something different. However, consider it as an bad design. The variable should be shared only between `do_sth` and `prepare_sth` threads. You can play with `args` and `kwargs` parameters to the `start()` method.

Comment: Well, I consider the generic situation is: when the preparer thread is ready, it is inherently blocked(and thus unable to set a variable), and the preparer thread should not set the variable in advance since the gap between the variable setting and thread being ready cannot be ignored. How should I deal with this case?

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific, how your expectations does not fit into lock and conditional variable scheme?